# Dim background for view of service app

Tags: android, service

I made a service app which displays a small view on screen when started.

Now i am trying to display a dim background behind it.

I tried theme tags like

android:backgroundDimEnabled = true

android:windowIsTranslucent = true

But no dim background appeared....please could anyone suggest any other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one method to achieve it :

When service launched then fire a intent to launch translucent activity in background.
That activity serves as dim background.